# Onclick button runs automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, onclick

I am new to HTML and JS. Im trying to inject a button into an existing page with a Chrome extension. I want to submit a search form when the button is clicked but at the moment it submits the form on page load and then repeatedly afterwards. What did I do wrong?

This is my manifest.json

```
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
    "content_scripts" : "script.js"
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://test.com/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"],  
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
```

and this is my script.js

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
var buttonName = document.createTextNode("Search By Tag");
  button.appendChild(buttonName);
    document.getElementById("nav-section").appendChild(button).onclick=window.location.href='https://test/search?....c';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your handler into function:

```
document.getElementById("nav-section").appendChild(button).onclick=function() { window.location.href='https://test/search?....c' };
```

Because currently you code is executed as:

1. Execute `window.location.href='https://test/search?....c';` Which immediately reloads your page.
2. Assign result of this execution to `onclick` handler. Which has no effect as your page reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a function in onclick properties. You can do it in following way.

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
var buttonName = document.createTextNode("Search By Tag");
button.appendChild(buttonName);
document.getElementById("nav-section").appendChild(button).onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://test/search?....c';
}
```